# trigger google adwords conversion jquery

Tags: jquery, google-ads-api

I'm trying to trigger a Google Adwords conversion using jQuery but not having any luck.  Here's the code i'm using.

The code is used to submit a form, which is then emailed to me.  The only part which does not work is the Google Conversion.

```
$.post('submit.php', $("form#easy").serialize(), function (data) {

        if (data == "Message sent")
        {
            $("div#error").hide();
            $("div#success").slideDown("fast");

            //Scroll to top of #form div - Useful if you have a fixed header
            var destination = $('div#form').offset().top - 0; //If you are using fixed header, change 0 to any height you wish
            $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({
                scrollTop: destination
            }, 200);

            // Clear form data
            $("#easy").reset();
            //Reload captcha when message is sent
            $('#vimage').attr('src', $('#vimage').attr('src')+'?'+Math.random());

            // Track conversion
            var google_conversion_id = "1016403774";
            var google_conversion_language = "en";
            var google_conversion_format = "3";
            var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
            var google_conversion_label = "wgx7CNj0vVYQvq7U5AM";
            var google_remarketing_only = false;
            $.getScript("http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js");

        } else {
            //PHP validation
            $("div#error").html(data).slideDown("fast");

            //Scroll to top of this div - 70px from the top of your view, change this to whatever number you wish
            var destination = $('div#form').offset().top - 70;
            $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({
                scrollTop: destination
            }, 200);

        }
    });
    return false;
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Thanks,
Bradley

Answer (score 0):

I would try looking at this answer:

[How do I adapt a Google AdWords tracking pixel for use in an AngularJS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410543/how-do-i-adapt-a-google-adwords-tracking-pixel-for-use-in-an-angularjs-app/22063668#22063668)

It was asked about AngularJS, but the answer is the same - you should use the asynchronous version of the conversion tag, and not try to force the standard one into an asynchronous environment.