# How to implement a Google Adwords "conversion pixel" using ajax on a submit button (no "thank you" page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-ads-api

I want to implement an adwords "conversion pixel" script - this is the script:

```
<!-- Google Code for General_Lead Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 000;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "hahaha";
var google_remarketing_only = false;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/975247275153/?label=IiuoCNO17lcQgZ2P0QM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

to a contact form on my website which doesn't lead to a "thank you" page. 
This is my submit form code. (The validation isn't 100% done :P )

```
// Send button for the "contact form".
$('#sendBtn').click(function(){
    //get info 
    var fullname = $("#fullname").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var text = $("#text").val();
    //send info to php 
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function() {
            if ( IsEmail(email) == false) {
                $('#aboutUnsuccess').show("slow");
                $('#contactform').hide("slow");
            }
        },
        url: 'http://www.example.com/contact.php', 
        type: "POST", 
        data: ({ "fullname": fullname, "email": email, "text": text }), 
        success: function (results){
            if ( IsEmail(email) == true) {
                //hide table 
                $('#contactform').hide('slow', function() {
                    $('#contactform').hide( "slow" );
                  });
                //show textboxes
                $('#aboutSuccess').show("slow");
            }
        }
    }); 


});
```

I tried using .append that I found out it doesn't work after googleing.

and tried to follow this post: [How to track a Google Adwords conversion onclick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082129/how-to-track-a-google-adwords-conversion-onclick) - which didn't work too

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Google supports async conversions:

https://developers.google.com/adwords-remarketing-tag/asynchronous/

Load this script in your html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

And then call the function `google_trackConversion` when your user clicks the button:

```
window.google_trackConversion({
    google_conversion_id: 1234,
    google_remarketing_only: true,
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Didn't find this while searching! :O 
Does this go right after 
'        success: function (results){'
?

Comment: if you want to make the conversion when the AJAX call is completed you put it in the success callback (just after `success: function(...) {`)

Comment: Thanks, 
There is no reference to the "google_conversion_label" parameter. 
Should this concern me?

Comment: I dont think so, I'm assuming that their example is intended to tell you that all the variables you would have put in global scope you now send in the object: eg: `window.google_conversion_id = xxx` becomes: `{ google_conversion_id: xxx }` and so on...

Comment: If you are using this snippet to do conversion tracking, make sure that google_remarketing_only is false, not true!

Comment: Matt1 - If possible - can you please tell why? Or at least link source upon which you have made this conclusion?

Answer (score 7):

100% working Google Conversion Tracking concept using Ajax on a submit button :

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "enquiry-submit.php",
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {
          $("#msg").fadeIn(400).html(result);

          /* Conversion Tracking Start */
          var google_conversion_id = YOUR_CONVERSION_ID_HERE;
          var google_conversion_language = "en";
          var google_conversion_format = "3";
          var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
          var google_conversion_label = "YOUR_CONVERSION_LABEL_HERE";
          var google_remarketing_only = false;

          $.getScript('//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js');

          var image = new Image(1, 1); 
          image.src = "//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/YOUR_CONVERSION_ID_HERE/?label=YOUR_CONVERSION_LABEL_HERE&guid=ON&script=0";  
          /* Conversion Tracking End */
        }
      });
```

It is working on my Google Ads Campaign.

**Note: You must try or test this by clicking on your ad. The effect of conversion will be visible after 15 minutes on your Google AdWords Console**

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.ajax({
   dataType: "script",
   cache: true,
   url: 'https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js'
 }).done(function () {
   isInitialized = true;
 });

google_trackConversion({
   google_conversion_id: 12345,
   google_conversion_language: "en",
   google_conversion_format: "3",
   google_conversion_color: "ffffff",
   google_conversion_label: "label",
   google_conversion_value: 0,
   google_remarketing_only: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

function for creating iframe and put adwords code in thanks.php file

```
function conversionTracker()  {
                var  iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                iframe.style.width = '0px';
                iframe.style.height = '0px';
                document.body.appendChild(iframe);
                iframe.src = 'thanks.php'; //Make sure path is correct! (update with bloginfo var for nebula)
            };
call conversionTracker() in ajax success function
....
success: function(response){
conversionTracker();
}
```

then create a thanks.php file and put adwords code in this file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Thank You</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>
    <!-- Google Code for Frachiseglobal Conversion Page -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var google_conversion_id = 1234;
    var google_conversion_language = "en";
    var google_conversion_format = "3";
    var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
    var google_conversion_label = "dummy";
    var google_conversion_value = 1.00;
    var google_conversion_currency = "INR";
    var google_remarketing_only = false;
    /* ]]> */
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
    </script>
    <noscript>
    <div style="display:inline;">
    <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/1234/?value=1&amp;currency_code=INR&amp;label=dsfdsf&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
    </div>
    </noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

Note : here label and conversion_id are fake values, Please put your own.